# Unable to convert this Character type to a proper Date type in R

Tags: r, dataset, posixct, string-to-datetime

I have a data set that has a column for dates (emp2$hiredate) which is in char format. While converting it to Date, I'm getting the following error :

```
> date1 <- emp2$hiredate[2]

> str(date1)
chr "20FEB1981"

> as.POSIXct(date1)
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R doesn't automatically know the format of the date in the string.   You need to use the `format` argument to tell it how to process the string.

You can use `as.Date` to create a date

```
as.Date("20FEB1981", "%d%b%Y")
# [1] "1981-02-20"
```

Or use `as.POSIXct` with the format option to create a date-time

```
as.POSIXct("20FEB1981", format = "%d%b%Y")
# [1] "1981-02-20 PST"
```

- `%d` means the day of the month in decimal form
- `%b` means that the month is not in numeric form, but rather an abbreviated name
- `%Y` (capitalized) means the year is in century form (all four numbers)